# A number of people wanted to, but the investigation failed to reveal they

Tags: pronouns, ellipses, whom

[Fowler reads](https://books.google.es/books?id=Sd3byNeBdR4C&lpg=PA861&ots=lD-ETunOIg&dq=%22There%20are%20a%20number%20of%20people%20who%20might%20have%20wanted%20to%20kill%20Robert%22&hl=es&pg=PA861#v=onepage&q=%22There%20are%20a%20number%20of%20people%20who%20might%20have%20wanted%20to%20kill%20Robert%22&f=false)

> “There are a number of people who might have wanted to kill Robert
> [...] , but the intervening two decades have failed to reveal **whom**
> [read **who**].”
>
> (Although **whom** might seem to be the object of reveal, in fact the
> relative pronoun is the subject of an implied verb—failed to reveal
> *who  [might have wanted to kill Robert]*).

Why exactly can't *whom* be used here, similarly to any personal pronoun, as in *...reveal **them** / **him or her (or them**)* ?

Secondly, could a nominative personal pronoun be used with a similar elliptical reasoning? E.g., ...reveal ***they** [who might have wanted to kill Robert]*

Comment: Fowler here (you don't specify which edition) is now out of date. 'We' don't say 'This is he'.  I'd say 'There are a number of people who might have wanted to kill Robert [...] , but the intervening two decades have failed to reveal who [they are]' is now virtually obligatory, and I'd always use the full version.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth full version?

Comment: Including 'they are'.

Answer (score 0):

The *who* that is used here is an interrogative pronoun, the only word in a reduced embedded interrogative clause. Similar to:

> We wondered [who might have wanted to kill Robert].
>
> Someone might have wanted to kill Robert. We wondered [who].

It cannot be a relative pronoun because present-day English does not allow fused relatives with a relativized subject using *who*.

> *Who might have wanted to kill Robert might also have wanted to kill his dog.

Even if the above were a valid construction, the notion of reducing a relative clause down to just the relative word is absurd. The word would invariably be interpreted as a reduced interrogative where possible, and produce an ungrammatical result otherwise,

> Mark gave me a gift. *I didn't like **what**.
>
> Jenny chose a place for the party. *We're all going **where** tomorrow.
>
> Bill chose a new partner. *I'm surprised at **who**.

with the exception of those with -ever suffixes.

> You can go with **whoever** [you like].

Hence, *who* must be subject in the embedded interrogative, excluding *whom*. Of course, if the understood interrogative were changed to query an object, then *whom* would be possible.

> Katy chose someone. She'll soon reveal **whom**.

A nominative pronoun could not be used because that would constitute a different construction - one without an embedded interrogative as complement to *reveal* - as there would be no interrogative word or phrase. The pronoun would simply figure as the object of *reveal* requiring the accusative case.